# Maximum number of concurrent client connections GRPC

Tags: java, c#, performance, websocket, grpc

I am currently conducting an assessment of the technology that can be used to develop an equity trading system and aim to have over 50,000 concurrent client connections to receive real time market data from the server. is it possible to implement **grpc** to achieve the goal? or is there a better option? please advice

Comment: I'm not sure SO is the right place for such a question. You are essentially asking for a benchmark comparing network protocols. There might be such benchmarks if you search a bit, but if these are unsatisfactory you probably need to make one yourself.

Comment: I agree with @JonasH that it might be not the best place to ask such questions and you probably need to make a benchmarking yourself. I can only add that if you really need high reliable concurrency and change of technology is acceptable, there is a whole language designed solely for this purpose called Erlang and is successfully being used for example by Discord.

Comment: thanks Jonas, Arthur. I appreciate with your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, but it will take some work to make it happen.   In Java, the the client-side load balancer is responsible for setting up and tearing down connections.  Two load balancers come by default: PickFirst and RoundRobin.

To run a realistic test, you probably want to copy-paste the [RoundRobin](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.47.x/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/util/RoundRobinLoadBalancer.java) implementation.  Unlike PickFirst, the RoundRobin implementation eagerly creates connections to the target address.  You can modify your copy to create 50,000 connections, and then use it when you set up your `ManagedChannel`.

The details on getting this to fully work probably each deserve their own question/answer, but from a high level, these breadcrumbs should let you run your own experiment to confirm that **yes, gRPC can handle tens of thousands of connections**.